# Bypass JPA/Hibernate cache and hit database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, caching, jpa

I've been struggling for some time with JPA (with Hibernate) to bypass the cache and hit the database.

We are constructing a framework  that receives the entity that must be saved, but in some cases, I need to check the current data on the database to determine which kind of update to execute (this is a business requirement).

So, I have an incoming attached entity updated by the user, but I need to verify its current database information to determine what business rule to execute (sometimes before and sometimes after the JPA merge() operation).

The only way I thought that it could work was to creating a brand new javax.persistence.EntityManager with the entity manager factory and with this new entity manager, execute the operation, but I got a concurrency error.

Look (this is inside a save() method in a DAO):

```
EntityManager newEM = currentEntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
newEM.find(e.getClass(), new Short("1"));
```

But when I try to execute the find() operation, I think that JPA will try to get the instance currently being managed by currentEntityManager instead of trying to hit the database.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not load an entity: [com.company.framework.persistence.model.TestEntity]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1694)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1141)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.find(Unknown Source)
```

Can you guys help me? This is a 2 weeks issue. I am really with no ideas.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new entityManager not using the code `currentEntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()`? Are you using FORCE WRITE as lock type? Or pessimist lock?

Comment: @uaiHebert I'm using JPA defaults and for concurrency control I'm using `@Version` fields. `currentEntityManager` is an injected DAO entity manager using `@PersistenceContext`. Which other way do you suggest me to create the entity manager that will hit the database and not the cache?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to inject the DataSource into your DAO, right beside your entity manager and create a JDBCTemplate:

```
 @Autowired
 private final DataSource dataSource;

 private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    jdbcTemplate = new JDBCTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Then use the jdbcTemplate to run your queries, because those will use a different JDBC connection than the EntityManager.

If the connection is bound to the current thread you need to execute your statement in a Callable submitted to an ExecutorService. Make sure you call the Future.get method on your callable result, so that the originating thread waits for the callable to finish.

In Java EE you can also mark your Bean methods with the @NotSupported transaction propagation. This will suspend the current transaction and execute your queries in a separate transaction.

Comment: thanks for you tip... I think that this will work but I really do not want to create a new data source because I already have an injected entity manager... I really can not believe that Hibernate/JPA does not give me an option to bypass the cache. This is such a common requirement. There must be another way lol :)

Comment: You don't have to create another data source. You can create only one and configure the entity manager factory to use it too. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I am not finding this annotation... in which package can I find it? Will I have a simple method in my DAO annotated with @NotSupported?

Comment: Check Adam Bien's example on extended persistence context: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/building_perfect_anti_facades_almost

Comment: In your case, you would need to call another Session Bean marked with this annotation.